# image slider arrows not responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive

I'm using High End theme and revolution slider plugin to add a slider to my home page. However, I noticed that the arrows aren't working properly, as the `<div>` are not responsive. That is, when I re-size the screen the arrows don't stick to the slider properly and go out of view.

I was hoping someone could help me out with this. I've tried messing with media queries and some other stuff, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The website is http://www.cmggroup.net

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 900px)

#main-wrapper .tparrows {
    display: none!important;
}
```

You this style is making arrows hidden below screen width of 900px

Try to add this into last .css file that you upload while rendering a page:

```
#main-wrapper .tparrows {
    display: block !important;
}
```

It should solve your problem, cheers!